# I would like to remove the X axis labels APEXCHARTS in NextJs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, next.js, charts, apexcharts

I would like to remove the X axis labels APEXCHARTS in NextJs.
[Image Exmple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hbrfv.png)
I would like to remove the number labels that go from 2100 to 8000.
I already tried with dataLabels, but it didn't work.

And I would also like to add points to each line, it could be one or more points.
....................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
  
'use client'
    import ReactApexChart from 'react-apexcharts';
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Show } from '@chakra-ui/react';
    
    
    interface GraficoDumbbleState {
      series: {
        data: { x: string; y: [number, number] }[];
        dataLabels?: {
          enabled: boolean;
        };
      }[];
      options: {
        chart: {
          height: number;
          type: string;
          zoom: {
            enabled: boolean;
          },
        };
        colors: string[];
        plotOptions: {
          bar: {
            horizontal: boolean;
            isDumbbell: boolean;
            dumbbellColors: string[][];
          };
        };
        title: {
          text: string;
        };
        legend: {
          show: boolean;
          showForSingleSeries: boolean;
          position: string;
          horizontalAlign: string;
          customLegendItems: string[];
        };
        fill: {
          type: string;
          gradient: {
            gradientToColors: string[];
            inverseColors: boolean;
            stops: number[];
          };
        };
        grid: {
          xaxis: {
            lines: {
              show: boolean;
            },
            
          };
          yaxis: {
            lines: {
              show: boolean;
            };
            yaxis: {
               lines: {
                 show: boolean 
                } 
              };
          };
        };
      };
    }
    
    class GraficoDumbble extends Component<{}, GraficoDumbbleState> {
        constructor(props: any) {
          super(props);
    
          this.state = {
          
            series: [
              {
                data: [
                  {
                    x: 'Amarela',
                    y: [2100, 8000]
                  },
                  {
                    x: 'Branca',
                    y: [2100, 8000]
                  },
                  {
                    x: 'Indígina',
                    y: [2100, 8000]
                  },
                  {
                    x: 'Parda',
                    y: [2100, 8000]
                  },
                  {
                    x: 'Preta',
                    y: [2100, 8000]
                  }
                ],
                dataLabels: {
                  enabled: false
                },
              }
            ],
            options: {
              chart: {
                height: 390,
                type: 'rangeBar',
                zoom: {
                  enabled: false
                },
              },
              colors: ['#808080', '#808080'],
              plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                  horizontal: true,
                  isDumbbell: true,
                  dumbbellColors: [['#808080', '#808080']],
                }
              },
              title: {
                text: '',
    
              },
              legend: {
                show: false,
                showForSingleSeries: false,
                position: 'top',
                horizontalAlign: 'left',
                customLegendItems: ['Female', 'Male']
              },
              fill: {
                type: 'gradient',
                gradient: {
                  gradientToColors: ['#808080'],
                  inverseColors: false,
                  stops: [0, 100]
                }
              },
              grid: {
                xaxis: {
                  lines: {
                    show: false
                  },
                },
                yaxis: {
                  lines: {
                    show: false
                  },
                  yaxis: { lines: { show: false } }
                }
              }
            },
          
          
          };
        }
        
    
        render() {
          return (
            <div>
              <div id="chart">
                <ReactApexChart options={this.state.options as any} series={this.state.series} type="rangeBar" height={390} />
              </div>
              <div id="html-dist"></div>
            </div>
          );
        }
      }
    
      
    export default GraficoDumbble;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to set `xaxis` object property `labels` property `show` to false, reference [documentation](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/grid/)

path to set: `options.xaxis.labels.show` to `false`

```
    ...
    grid: {
        ...
    },
    xaxis: {
      labels: {
        show: false,
      }
    },
    ...
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-hl2aq8)